# Test Ajax-submit a form in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, forms, unit-testing, wicket

Suppose I have a form as shown below, which is submitted via Ajax:

```java
import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

public class FormPage extends WebPage {
    public FormPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        Form form = new Form("myForm");
        // Ajax submit
        form.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("onsubmit") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                super.onSubmit(target); // Breakpoint on this line
            }
        });
        add(form);
    }   
}
```

Now I need to test the form, and set a breakpoint in the onSubmit method. Here is the test code:

```java
import org.apache.wicket.util.tester.FormTester;
import org.apache.wicket.util.tester.WicketTester;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestFormPage {
    private WicketTester tester;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        tester = new WicketTester(new WicketApplication());
    }

    @Test
    public void homepageRendersSuccessfully() {
        tester.startPage(FormPage.class);
        tester.assertRenderedPage(FormPage.class);

        FormTester formTester = tester.newFormTester("myForm");
        formTester.submit();        
    }
}
```

But the problem is, when I run the unit test, the line with breakpoint set is never reached. Wonder what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the test, the following line would submit a normal form, but would not fire the Ajax submit event.

```java
formTester.submit();
```

In order to fire the Ajax submit event, WicketTester#executeAjaxEvent should be used instead, as shown below:

```java
import org.apache.wicket.util.tester.WicketTester;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestFormPage {
    private WicketTester tester;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        tester = new WicketTester(new WicketApplication());
    }

    @Test
    public void homepageRendersSuccessfully() {
        tester.startPage(FormPage.class);
        tester.assertRenderedPage(FormPage.class);

        tester.executeAjaxEvent("myForm", "submit");    
    }
}
```

Ref:

- https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/testing.html
- https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html